# UILocalNotification: Cancel all on specific days

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification

My App needs to trigger alarms at weekdays only.
My idea was to schedule notifications for each day, but the problem is that I read that 64 scheduled notifications are the maximum you can have and with my notifications there will be a total of 120 notifications so this can't be done.

Now I'm wondering if there is a way to cancel all the notifications on Saturday and Sunday instead.

The code I am using now that repeats the notification in weekends to:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [comps setHour:8];
    [comps setMinute:25];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDate *fireDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];

    UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    alarm.fireDate = fireDate;
    alarm.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    alarm.soundName = @"sound.aiff";
    alarm.alertBody = @"Message..";
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
```

Comment: You can always check a week day when you init your notification with date/time. Can you show me your code where you set up your notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `[UIApplication scheduledLocalNotifications]`, you have all notification scheduled.

It's an array of `UILocalNotification`.

Make a loop with this array and look at the date `fireDate` of the notification, and do :

```
[UIApplication cancelLocalNotification:theNotificationToDelete];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however I don't know what you mean. My notification works fine but repeats every day and I want it to cancel them all at Saterday and Sunday.

Comment: You have scheduled all notifications for each day in advance ?

Comment: I just created 24 notifications, and set the repeat to Daily, because I can't schedule 120 notifications because of Apple's limit.

Comment: I understand but you can schedule your notifications daily with a for loop instead of the daily parameter.

Comment: Do you have any example code how I can achieve this, in which direction should I start coding?

Comment: I have write the algorithm, you just have to implement it !

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what to do, could please be more specific.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but could you please push me in the right direction since I'm unsure what to do now.